# Android application project missing from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I'm new to Eclipse and Android and have followed the steps to installing the Android SDK, eclipse and ADT plugin.

On trying to create my first app from here:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

"In the window that appears, open the Android folder, select Android Application Project, and click Next."

I dont see the Android folder? What am I missing?

Comment: It might be that you haven't installed android sdk correctly. Did you restart the eclipse after installing the SDK stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to quit and restart Eclipse after installing the SDK etc.?